# Don't stretch element's height based on the one next to it

Tags: html, css, height, width

So I have this list with float list items inside of it, with width equal to 50%. They are all dynamically generated and some li have bigger height then the wrest and the one that's next to it stretches to that height and kinda looks weird. And I don't want it to stretch. Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>Some label</span>
        Some text
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Some label</span>
        Some text
        <ul>
            <li><strong>More options</strong></li>
            <li>Option 1</li>
            <li>Option 2</li>
            <li>Option 3 </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Some label</span>
        Some text
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Some label</span>
        Some text
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul > li {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

ul > li li {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
}
```

JSFiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/y160n4hg/

Comment: You will have to change the DOM for that

Comment: then you need to split your <ul> into two. i.e <ul><li>..</li><li>..</li></ul> <ul><li>..</li><li>..</li></ul>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/y160n4hg/5/)**

CSS:

```
#container {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0;
    -webkit-column-fill: auto;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 0;
    /*  -moz-column-fill: auto;*/
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 0;
    column-fill: auto;
}
ul.one {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
ul.one >li {  
    background:green;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    vertical-align:top;
}
ul.one li li {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    background:yellow;
}

ul.one li > ul >li {
    color: red;
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container"> <ul class="one">..</ul></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set max-height to the LI element and set overflow auto to get a scroll bar to scroll through values.

```css
ul > li {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    max-height: 70px;
    overflow: auto;
}

ul > li li {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>Some label</span>
        Some text
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Some label</span>
        Some text
        <ul>
            <li><strong>More options</strong></li>
            <li>Option 1</li>
            <li>Option 2</li>
            <li>Option 3 </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Some label</span>
        Some text
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Some label</span>
        Some text
    </li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y160n4hg/3/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this modified version: https://jsfiddle.net/scarl3tt/y160n4hg/1/

I've added this code to demonstrate the fact that the list items aren't actually stretching - they're just floating down.

```
ul > li {
    ...
    background: red;
}
```

Float doesn't automatically push things as high as they can go. There are javascript libraries to squish content like that for you, though they're pretty gross. [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) is one of the more popular ones.

Answer (score 0):

try this

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><span>Some Label 1-1</span> Some text</li>
    <li><span>Some Label 1-2</span> Some text</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li> <span>Some Label 2-1</span> Some text
        <br> <strong>More Options</strong>

        <ul>
            <li>Some More Text</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span>Some Label 2-2</span> Some text</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {    
    float:left;
}
li ul {
    float:none;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/je1wmzmf/)